# Convert a Word document into PDF file

Tags: windows, pdf

I have Adobe Acrobat Reader on my laptop. I want to convert a Word document into PDF file. When I try to save the file, I don't find a PDF file format on the *Save as type* box.

Comment: What version of Word?

Comment: If you have the option in your Word you can do it

Comment: "I have Adobe Acrobat Reader on my laptop" - that is only for opening pdf files. To convert .doc to pdf you need to have a document editor (Microsoft Word,  OpenOffice Writer...) installed,  that can be capable to save as pdf,  or you need a "pdf printer" to.

Comment: As mentioned Word usually can save PDF but you might want to install [PDF24](https://en.pdf24.org/) nevertheless in order to be able to generate pdfs from all programs that can print.

Answer (score 2):

Office 2010 or later include the option to save documents (including Word) as PDF files. If you have Office 2007 you need to download the [Save As PDF add-in](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7) from Microsoft first.

To save an Office document as a PDF, do the following:

1. On the *File* tab of the ribbon (Office button for Office 2007), click **Export**
2. Click **Create PDF/XPS Document** (twice)

   **Note:** The two steps above are slightly different for Office 2007/2010. You need to click **Save As**
3. In the *Save As* dialog box, make sure the File type is PDF

Answer (score 1):

The way I approached this problem was to install some pdf printer. I used to use [doPDF](http://www.dopdf.com/)

Once this is installed in your system, you could go to the print dialog, and you should be able to print as PDF.

Comment: You can have it as option in Microsoft Office

Answer (score 1):

There is a Microsoft official tool for Office 2007
you can download it from here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7

in this link you have information how to save files as PDF
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Save-or-convert-to-PDF-d85416c5-7d77-4fd6-a216-6f4bf7c7c110

Steps:
1. you need to choose what version was installed in your computer

**Word 2007:**
Click the Microsoft Office Button  Office button image , point to the arrow next to Save As, and then click PDF or XPS.

In the File Name list, type or select a name for the document.

In the Save as type list, click PDF.

If you want to open the file immediately after saving it, select the Open file after publishing check box. This check box is available only if you have a PDF reader installed on your computer.

Next to Optimize for, do one of the following, depending on whether file size or print quality is more important to you:

If the document requires high print quality, click Standard (publishing online and printing).

If the print quality is less important than file size, click Minimum size (publishing online).

Click Options to set the page range to be printed, to choose whether markup should be printed, and to select the output options. (Find links to more information on these options in the See Also section.) Click OK.

Click Publish.

**Word 2010 - the last version:**

Choose File > Export > Create PDF/XPS.

Create PDF/XPS button on the Export tab in Word 2016.
If the properties of your Word document contains information that you do not want included in the PDF, in the Publish as PDF or XPS window, choose Options. Then select Document and clear Document properties. Set any other options you want and choose OK.

Clear Document properties to avoid sharing that information in the PDF file.
For more information about document properties, see View or change the properties for an Office 2016 file.

In Publish as PDF or XPS, navigate to where you want to save the file. Also, modify the file name if you want a different name.

Click Publish.

Comment: It is better to add information with the Link

Comment: Only Office 2007 requires downloading anything. Office 2010+ can save as PDF natively.